# How do you send XML post request using rest-assured?

Tags: rest-assured

I have to send a post request with xml data and then validate the response like example checking the status code and response body.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any specific issues with code you have written?

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass a pojo (remember to set the content-type to application/xml) and rest assured will automatically transform it into XML. For example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Greeting {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
greeting.setFirstName("John");
greeting.setLastName("Doe");

given().contentType(ContentType.XML).and().body(object).when().post("/somewhere"). ..
```

it'll send the following XML:

```
<greeting>
   <firstName>John</firstName>
   <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</greeting>
```

Let's say that the server is responding with the same XML as the one you see above then you can validate the response status code and body like this:

```
given().
        contentType(ContentType.XML).
        body(object).
when().
        post("/somewhere").
then().
        statusCode(200).
        body("greeting.firstName", equalTo("John")).
        body("greeting.lastName", equalTo("Doe"));
```

REST Assured will automatically understand the the response body is XML if the server returns an XML content-type. Note that `equalTo` is statically imported from `org.hamcrest.Matchers#equalTo`.